# Is there a limit which characterizes twice differentiability?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is twice differentiable at $x=a$, then we have

$$
f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h) }{h^2}
$$

However there are functions which are not twice differentiable for which this limit exists (for example, the signum function).

Is there a limit definition for $f''(a)$ which exists iff $f$ is twice differentiable?

Comment: Disregard the previous comment

Comment: No!!! A derivative is defined in terms of values of the function and hence the second derivative is defined in terms of values of first derivative. There is no way to define second derivative in terms of values of function if we restrict ourselves to the theory of functions of single real variable.

Comment: @RRL Do you think it is better to post a new question?  I agree I was not precise enough.  Here is another stab at it:  Is there an expression for the second derivative in terms of only limits (possibly of several variables), algebraic operations, and the function $f$ which accomplishes the following:  This limit exists only when the function $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$.  The limit exists only when $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$.  The value of the limit is $f''(a)$.

Comment: Perhaps.  I think you made some progress here.  Here is my take. The iterated limit converges to the second derivative (when it exists along with other technical requirements). Remember derivatives are not even defined unless the point is an accumulation point in the domain.  For sufficiently smooth behavior limits like the original posted converge to the correct value.  That convergence may not be sufficient for existence of the second derivative.  I would be curious to find a counterexample where the forward difference converges but $f''$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just iterate the definition of the derivative: we see that $f$ is differentiable if the limit

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

exists. Then $f$ is twice differentiable if the limit

$$f''(x) = \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f'(x+k) - f'(x)}{k}$$

exists. Plugging in the definition for the first derivative, we see $f$ is twice differentiable if the double limit

\begin{align*} 
f''(x) 
&= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+k+h)-f(x+k)}{h} - \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}}{k}\\  
&= \lim_{k\to 0} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+k+h)-f(x+k)-f(x+h)+f(x)}{hk}
\end{align*}

exists. Of course, if this limit exists, this would imply that

$$f''(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}$$

I'm not sure that we can use the latter as a definition since it would be derived from taking a specific value for $k$; that being said, I don't have a specific example where the latter limit exists at a point but the function is not twice differentiable there.

Comment: In my question, I mention that the signum function at $x=0$ makes this limit exist, but is not twice differentiable (or even continuous) at $x=0$.

I would like a proof that your combined limit exists iff $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: I'm not sure it does make that limit exist at $x=0$ though. Remember, $k,h$ can be positive or negative. It certainly doesn't make OP's limit exist at $a = 0$ so I don't see a problem with this.

Comment: This made sense until I saw limits approaching infinity. Should those limits approach zero?

Comment: @John I edited it to 0 instead of infinity.  This was surely just a mistake.

Comment: @User8128  Despite the fact that it solves the problem for the signum function, this is not a proof that this limit exists iff the second derivative exists.  I will try to work on this and post an answer.

Comment: I am also curious about the joint limit $\lim_{h,k \to 0}$ instead of the double limit.

Comment: Using Taylor with Lagrange remainder (which assumes that $f$ is twice differentiable but not necessarily $f \in C^2$) sheds a different light on the issue: $\begin{cases}f(x+h)&=&f(x)+hf'(x)+(h^2/2)f''(x+c_1h) & (1)\\ f(x)&=&f(x)&(2)\\ f(x-h)&=&f(x)-hf'(x)+(h^2/2)f''(x+c_2h) & (3)\end{cases}$ with $0 \leq c_1,c_2 \leq 1$. It suffices to do $ (1)-2 \times (2)+(3)$ and let $h$ tend to zero to get the result.

Comment: @StevenGubkin if the second derivative exists, then certainly the OP's limit exists. That's all I was saying. I agree that if the OP's limit exists, the second derivative may still not exist. And yes, sorry for the typo with $\infty$; I meant 0.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears to be is there a difference approximation involving a single increment $h$ such that the approximation converges to the value of the second derivative as $h \to 0$ if and only if the second derivative exists.

The definition of the second derivative at a point $x$ is
$$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(x+h)- f'(x)}{h},$$

assuming that the first derivative is defined in a neighborhood of $x$.

As suggested in another answer this can be written as an iterated limit

$$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{f(x+h+k)- f(x+h) +f(x+k) + f(x)}{hk}.$$

Nothing has been proved yet as this is just a restatement of the definition.

The appropriate question now --  raised by the OP in comments -- is under what conditions does the double limit as $h,k \to 0$ converge to the same value:

$$f''(x) = \lim_{h,k \to 0}\frac{f(x+h+k)- f(x+h) -f(x+k) + f(x)}{hk}.$$

If so, then the diagonal limit with $h = k$ must converge and we have

$$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)- 2f(x+h) + f(x)}{h^2}.$$

Note that the iterated limits can be switched, but this is merely a consequence of symmetry and does not guarantee that the double limit exists.  There are, of course, many well known examples where the iterated limits converge to the same value but the double limit fails to exist.

If, however, the inner limit is uniformly convergent then the double limit exists. This is guaranteed when the second derivative is bounded in some neighborhood of $x$.  Then we have by Taylor's theorem

$$f(x+h+k) = f(x+h) + f'(x+h)k + f''(\xi)k^2/2, $$

and

$$\left|\frac{f(x+h+k) - f(x+h)}{k} - f'(x+h)\right| =  |f''(\xi)k/2| \leqslant Mk/2. $$

Then the LHS is uniformly convergent to $0$ as $k \to 0$ for all $x+h$ 
in the neighborhood where the second derivative is bounded.

A bounded second derivative in a neighborhood is, therefore, a sufficient condition for the forward difference approximation (and the central difference approximation) to converge to the correct value in conjunction with existence of the second derivative.

The signum function is a somewhat of a distraction here.  Since the second derivative fails to exist at $x = 0$ then the convergence of the central difference to $0$ while surprising is not relevant.  It is purely an artifact of the cancelation of terms for this particular function. In this case, the forward approximation will diverge to $\infty$ as one might expect.

Comment: This is all quite nice, but still does not investigate whether (for instance) the convergence of the double limit does or does not imply the existence of the second derivative.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: Convergence of the double limit is the strongest convergence. It implies convergence of the iterated limit which by definition implies the existence of the second derivative.  My point is about whether taking the limit with $h = k$ is OK --  and it is when the double limit converges.

Comment: Let's be sure we are talking about the same thing. Double limit means $f(h,k) \to L$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $h,k < \delta \implies |f(h,k) - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I have to think a bit about whether I agree that the iterated limit existing really does immediately imply that the first derivative exists.  My worry is that perhaps neither f'(x+k) or f'(x) exist, but summing these "before taking a limit" leads to something which converges.

Comment: For instance, consider $f(x) = \begin{cases}1 \textrm{ if $x<0$} \\ 0 \textrm{ if $0\leq x \leq 1$}\\ 1 \textrm{ if x>1}\end{cases}$.  Then $\lim_{h \to 0} \left[ \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} + \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\right]$ exists, although each limit does not individually.

Comment: Exactly -- which is why I stated in my answer that the definition of the second derivative (the derivative of the derivative) needs a well defined first derivative.  The question is still OK in the context of how do various finite difference approximations behave when the derivatives exist.  If you believe in the definition of the second derivative as the iterated limit, then this is all about if we can set $h=k.$

Comment: I probably should have put more time and effort into my question, but this was just sparked by idle curiosity:  part of my question was really whether a single limit could capture both the existence of the first derivative in a neighborhood of $a$ (so that the second derivative makes sense), the existence of the second derivative at $a$, and the value of that second derivative.

Comment: I still think there is a chance that the double limit actually **does** capture all of this information.  At least until I see a concrete counterexample.  My counter example above (for $x =0$ , $k=1$ ) does not work when you allow $k$ to vary.